# Is QGIS suitable to create maps with image popups?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

I am a new user of QGIS and was wondering if I came across the right software to achieve my goal.

Long story short, I am trying to create a map with markups of various buildings. Once I click on a mark, I would like to see details of that property and possibly a photo. 
Further more I would like to integrate this map on my website.

Can you please advise me if QGIS can help me achieve this? Or would you have a better recommendation? I can see that the software capabilities are far more advanced than the purpose of my goal, but thought of asking for your advice.

Many thanks.

George

Comment: Well, QGIS works fine with thematic mapping. You can create your map and then use the identifier to click on your marks and get data - though I am not sure you can view images..

Now, making an interactive map available in a web site is a different case. You would need to use tools such as openlayers api, geoserver, postgis etc. Not all of them necessarily. Google some info about interactive map sharing/publish etc.

Comment: Hi Antony, many thanks for your reply. I am doing a bit of research on google. I guess even google maps could work in the end although it seems the I cannot number the buildings. Also looking at google fusion which exports locations from cvs files and adds markups on the maps. I would like to do something reliable and add free. Again, many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you found the right tool for *creating* your data. QGIS is mainly for creating the information not necessarily for sharing the information.

Luckily what you are wanting is actually kind of trivial in QGIS and with something like Google Maps but you need some background knowledge.  If you know nothing about GIS it might seem daunting at first but quickly becomes common knowledge.  I bold words that will help you on your search for knowledge, but this process, especially without GIS background is bit beyond SE format.  But I can give you an idea of how to get there.

But your will need to pickup some basic understanding of **projections**, **datum**, and **coordinate systems**.  Without this knowledge your map may show your feature in different locations then expected.

Next you need to learn how to **digitize** your features using QGIS and save them into the easiest format which is a **shapefile**.  Create polygons, point and line that you will overlay onto your mapping application.  If you have images that do not have georeference to them, then you need to know how to **georeference** and/or **rubber-sheet** an image.

Once you have your data all ready you just have to export it from QGIS to a format that you can use with your mapping application.  Exporting to **KML**(Keyhole Markup Language) is a good option, it save your data(your details) and the features you digitized.

Using Google Maps and KML is stupid-easy, they work out of the box. As do a lot of mapping application out there.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

To get an image to appear in the balloon is a little more work.  Involves embedding HTML into the KML file but with a little work you can do it.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open pictures in QGIS using "Layer options" -> "Actions" then read picture link from database and execute your program. WWW is little bit different case, but you can "easily" share same postgis database and images between qgis and some geoserver + openlayers code